How to fix unresponsive keyboard on Lenovo 82AS Yoga Duet 7 13IML05
Issue: Built in detachable keyboard and touchpad stop working moment system starts loading .(Keyboard work in bios, Windows and GRUB/Systemd-boot).
Device: 82AS Yoga Duet 7 13IML05, CPU: Intel i7-10510U (8) @ 4.900GHz, GPU: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Kernel: 6.10.7-arch1-1
What i have do so far:
I traced the issue to i8042 which in my poor understanding deals with ps/2
# dmesg | grep i8042
[    0.000000] Command line: initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=PARTUUID=c6a26a9e-3ea1-486a-8d4f-5d53ffb8a7ee zswap.enabled=0 rw rootfstype=ext4 i8042.reset=1
[    0.080606] Kernel command line: initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=PARTUUID=c6a26a9e-3ea1-486a-8d4f-5d53ffb8a7ee zswap.enabled=0 rw rootfstype=ext4 i8042.reset=1
[    1.135113] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.135119] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    1.139335] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.332642] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3

So i added script 'keyboard-reset.sh' to /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ and the keyboard and touchpad start working after suspending the device into sleep mode.
script  'keyboard-reset.sh':
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
    pre/*)
        rmmod i8042
        ;;
    post/*)
        modprobe i8042 reset=1
        ;;
esac

credits to mistine at github
But it doesn't enable keyboard after system boot.
Following didn't seem to work

adding params atkbd.reset=1 i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset=1 i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1 to entry in /boot/loader/entries/...
making a service /usr/lib/systemd/system/keyboard-reset.service and later also at systemd/system/keyboard-reset.service that runs mentioned script keyboard-reset.sh

keyboard-reset.service
   [Unit]
   Description=reseting i8042
   After=systemd-user-sessions.service
   Before=getty.target

   [Service]
   ExecStart= /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/keyboard-reset.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target

Any help is welcomed.
